# MySQL GUI Programs

Tags: mysql

Are there any programs with a gui which let you create a MySQL database, create tables, define the primary and foreign keys and insert data? I am tired of having to use the mysql command line client, very tedious.

Comment: What development environment are you using? Some IDEs (like Visual Studio Team System) provide database project types which allow facilitate creation, management and deployment of all db entities (tables, sprocs, etc) from the IDE itself. Also makes versioning very easy.

Comment: Any preferences on a web gui over a desktop gui (or vice-versa)?

Answer (score 8):

I suggest you use [phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/). There is also [MySQL Workbench](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/).

Answer (score 6):

- [MySQL Query Browser](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) (`MySQL`)
- [pgAdmin III](http://www.pgadmin.org/) (`PostgreSQL`)
- [Allround Automations](http://www.allroundautomations.com/doa.html) PL/SQL Developer (`Oracle`)
- [SQL Server Management Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213248.aspx) (`SQL Server`)

Answer (score 4):

these app arn't free but useful :

1. [SQLYOG](http://www.webyog.com/en/sqlyog_feature_matrix.php)
2. [Navicat](http://www.navicat.com/)

Comment: There is a free version of SQLyog. It is called the Community edition.

Answer (score 3):

[SQLyog Community Edition](http://code.google.com/p/sqlyog/). The Community Edition is Free & Open Source under GPL license.

Comment: This is by far the best IDE for working with MySQL. I love it so much i actually paid for the full version.

Answer (score 3):

If you happen to be using Mac OSX, I highly recommend http://www.sequelpro.com/ (it's free and awesome).

Comment: Great suggestion! But as of 2021 SequelPro seems to be unmaintained, and is hard to get to work with the latest versions of MySql. SequelAce (https://github.com/Sequel-Ace/Sequel-Ace) is a fork of SequelPro that is maintained and works with MySql version 8.

Answer (score 2):

Toad is free and very powerful

Comment: toad is free? are you sure? if you mean this http://www.quest.com/toad/ , it looks like there is just a free trial.