# How do I setup a GUI to MySql?

Tags: php, mysql, node.js

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MySQL GUI Programs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2738737/mysql-gui-programs)

I have installed MySql 5.5 on my PC (win7), but all I have is a cmd window to control it, is there any GUI like in Microsoft SQL Server?

I use node.js and PHP.

Comment: [MySQL Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/).

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/gui-tools/5.0.html

Comment: Notice the question is for node.js, there is no duplicate it this question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few options. Very common options are MySQL Workbench or PhpMyAdmin.

http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/downloads.php
http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/5.1.html

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try Navicat (http://www.navicat.com/). Its not free but I think there is a (free) Lite version. In any case its great!

Also, PHPMyAdmin in case you are pairing it with Apache / PHP (http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php). Its a web tool that lets you administer you mysql db. Also great.

Answer (score 1):

There are several tools available.  Phpmyadmin is one option.  Really a google search for "mysql gui" will give you man options right there.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to recommend three tools.
1. Navicat, which is a commercial ware, tradition desktop application, really cool and almighty.
2. MySQL Workbench, which could be downloaded from MySQL official site. It's a free desktop application, but the performance is not as good as Navicat.
3. PHPMyAdmin, which is also free and cool, but you need to set up a LAMP/WAMP environment and use it inside a web browser.